# in insert query how to use id value from another table

Tags: php

This is form code from which i jump to sql insert query how i use the id of previous page to next to next page

```
<?php
$item=$_GET['category_id'];
echo '<tr><a href="additem.php"> <button type="button" name="btn1" 
class="btn btn-primary">Add Category</button></a></tr>';

if ($item==1) {
    $query="SELECT * FROM  tbl_items where category_id=1";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href=""><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src=images/<?php echo $row['image']; ?> width="50" height="50"> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: what previous page, what next page? where is the form?

Comment: Where is your insert query?

Answer (score 1):

I you want pagination tutorial then please find this url.
[Tuts Plush PHP pagination guide.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928)